# Django Model does not create data field

Tags: django-models

I added new model to my database, but Django does not add its.
My models is:

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse

class Toolbox(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Toolbox'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Toolboxs'

    building = models.ForeignKey('Building', on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name='toolboxes')

    STATUS = [('A','Avaible'),
            ('U','Unavaiable'),
    ]
    Rent_status = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices= STATUS)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-pk']
        verbose_name = 'Toolbox'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Toolboxes'

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Toolbox ID %s, Buidling %s, Status %s' % (self.pk, self.building, self.Rent_status)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('Toolbox_view', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

class Building(models.Model):
    Adress = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-Adress']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Adress

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('building_toolbox', args = [self.pk])

class Toolbox_rental(models.Model):
    Toolbox_ID = models.ForeignKey('Toolbox', on_delete = models.CASCADE, primary_key= True, related_name='Toolbox_rentals'),
    Rent_date = models.DateField(null = True, blank = True),
    Return_date = models.DateField(null = True, blank = True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Toolbox_rental'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Toolbox_rentals'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Toolbox_ID
```

I registered the new model in admin already but when I go to admin to add the date, Django does not creatte all needed data field
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the comma's at the end of the field definitions of your Toolbox_rental model. Try changing it to the following:

```
class Toolbox_rental(models.Model):
    Toolbox_ID = models.ForeignKey('Toolbox', on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True, related_name='Toolbox_rentals')
    Rent_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    Return_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Toolbox_rental'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Toolbox_rentals'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Toolbox_ID
```